# Using ecryptfs encrypted home directories with Dovecot

Tags: ubuntu, pam, dovecot, ecryptfs

I have setup home directory encryption on Ubuntu 10.04 machine, but `ecryptfs` does not seem to be able to work with `Dovecot` (or `CourierIMAP`, etc).

After successful IMAP login, home directory is never mounted, and Dovecot obviously can not find mail directory.

I am not sure I understand how the mount is triggered, so I need some help.

`Dovecot` is using PAM, so I hoped that after successful login home directory would be mounted, but this is all I get in logs and directory is not mounted:

```
Jan 16 02:12:37 ubuntu dovecot-auth: pam_sm_authenticate: Called
Jan 16 02:12:37 ubuntu dovecot-auth: pam_sm_authenticate: username = [username]
Jan 16 02:12:37 ubuntu dovecot-auth: Passphrase file wrapped
Jan 16 02:12:38 ubuntu dovecot-auth: Error attempting to add filename encryption key to user session keyring; rc = [1]
Jan 16 02:12:38 ubuntu dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<username>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured
```

If I create an SSH session and then perform IMAP login, it works (obviously) but I get this:

```
Jan 16 02:30:25 ubuntu dovecot-auth: pam_sm_authenticate: Called
Jan 16 02:30:25 ubuntu dovecot-auth: pam_sm_authenticate: username = [username]
Jan 16 02:30:25 ubuntu dovecot-auth: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/username is already mounted
```

So, it does seem like `Dovecot` (well, PAM module, I guess) is trying to mount the home directory, but it either mounts and dismounts it immediately or something else happen - and I am unable to figure out that part.

I have also tried using SSHD's PAM file for `Dovecot`, but nothing really changed, except the fact I was not getting the error message ("Error attempting to add filename encryption key to user session keyring...").

On Ubuntu community Dovecot page (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot) there is a paragraph that says:

> NOTE: Dovecot will NOT work in an encrypted directory/folder. Dovecot would just complain about permissions and wont work. One answer is to create a 2nd user account that has an unencrypted home directory. We have not tested this solution on a separate home partition, but most probably the outcome would be the same.

However, I am not sure if this is definitive answer (and I don't understand what they mean with having 2nd user account).

I would appreciate if someone could tell me if it is possible to use `Dovecot` (with mail directory inside user's home directory) with `ecryptfs`.

I have seen this question (and borrowed some wording from it :) on Launchpad's `ecryptfs` questions page (but no answer to it), so seems like I am not the only one with the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that pam_ecryptfs captures and uses your login passphrase to decrypt `~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase`, and perform your home directory mount.

Unfortunately the non-interactive dovecot pam session that you describe doesn't ever actually snag your login passphrase, so it cannot perform the mount.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have never set it up myself. Your error seems to indicate that Dovecot opens a PAM session then immediately closes it. Could you post the relevant passages from you Dovecot config as well as `/etc/pam.d/dovecot` ?

> I have also tried using SSHD's PAM file for Dovecot, but nothing really changed, except the fact I was not getting the error message ("Error attempting to add filename encryption key to user session keyring...").

Do you get an error message in this case ? Is PAM debugging enabled in you Dovecot config ? If not, use the following :

```
passdb pam {
  args = failure_show_msg=yes
}
```

Here are a few of the elements I would check :

1. Are you passing `session=yes` to PAM ? You should not in this instance.
2. Is lookup caching disabled in Dovecot ?
3. If you are using Dovecot < 1.1, ensure that you're using non-forking lookups

Comment: I apologize, didn't get email notification about an answer, and I gave up on this long time ago anyway. Do I need to accept this answer? I do not have the setup available for testing anymore, so it is kind of pointless for me to try to continue the discussion.